# RxJava Completable Concat

Tags: java, rx-java

Consider following snippet:

```
@Test
public void completableConcatTest() {
    Completable.concat(completableTwoSeconds(), completableTwoSeconds())
            .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("Both completed."))
            .await();
}

private Completable completableTwoSeconds() {
    PublishSubject<Void> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        subject.onCompleted();
        return null;
    });

    return subject.doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("I'm completed." + Instant.now())).toCompletable();
}
```

When run, test produces following output:

```
I'm completed.2018-05-11T10:07:26.359Z
I'm completed.2018-05-11T10:07:26.380Z
Both completed.
```

Obviously, two completables run in parallel, not serially as intended.

Can you please explain what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CompletableFuture`s pretty much start executing immediately upon declaration, which you do in `completableTwoSeconds()` way before RxJava and `concat` gets involved. You have to defer at least the second call to `completableTwoSeconds()` in order to have it execute after the first completes:

```java
Completable.concat(
    completableTwoSeconds(), 
    Completable.defer(() -> completableTwoSeconds())
)
.doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("Both completed."))
.await();
```